# Removing a pattern from text file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file riddled with this kind of thing:

```
-POEM-
>> The big brown fox
>> jumps over the
>> lazy dog.
The end.
```

I want to get rid of "\n>>" and just turn this into a oneliner:

```
-POEM-
The big brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The end.
```

I'm trying the following, all of which refuse to work:

```
perl -pe 's/\r?\n>>//g' task.tex
tr '\n\>\>' '' < task.tex 
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n>>//g' task.tex
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to run through so much of trouble? Here's what I just did with your piece of text.

1. Open the file in GEdit.
2. Keep the cursor on the start of the second line
3. Use CTRL + H (Find and replace)
4. Find for `>>` and replace with SPACE
5. Find for `\n` and replace with SPACE

Make sure you use REPLACE ALL in both cases (4 and 5).

That's what I did and it worked :)

Comment: This would work just fine. Not sure why you would need to over complicate such a task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is in a file called `x.txt`:

```
tr -d '\n>>' < x.txt | sed -e 's/-POEM-/&\n/' -e 's/\./&\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
while read line; do
         line1=`echo $line`;
         if [ `echo $line1 | grep "^>" | wc -l` -eq 1 ];
         then
                 var1=`echo $line1 | sed 's/^...//'`;
                 line2=`echo $line2 $var1`;
         else
                 echo $line2;
                 echo $line1;
         fi;
done < task.tex
```

Comment: It is not necessary to fork a new subshell process just to assign the contents of a shell variable to another shell variable.

Comment: Thanks for aligning the code.. please also let me know a generic code for doing the above mentioned task!!! As the answer by Ketan is input specific.